# jquery ui droppable but not some child elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to drag and drop but exclude some child elements from the drop zone with jQueryUI Droppable like:

```
<div id="dropZone">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>exclude this container</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use jQueryUI draggable/droppable. It has several parameters which will allow you to control what is/is not an acceptable drop zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cancel option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) to prevent dragging some elements like below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="dropZone">
  <div class="child">child1</div>
  <div class="child">child2</div>
  <div class="child disable">exclude this container</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$( "#dropZone .child").draggable({
  cancel: ".disable"
});
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/n54j9kpf/10/)

Comment: thank for your reply, it's not really disable the draggable child bhut rather disable droppable child, i fix that by using js and check position with offset (top / left).

Comment: @ITS You are welcome. Please up-vote my answer for knowing other people that it helps you because some people only see the up-voted answers.